# Change title url of elementtype in the list

Tags: plugin-development, admin, elementtype, extends

I have a plugin. In this plugin I did elementtype which extends the user one, but with only one source "clients". I have and New Client button which points to my plugin `Plugin_ClientController` which looks like this:

```
class Plugin_ClientController extends UsersController
{

    public function actionIndex( array $variables = array() ) {

       $this->renderTemplate('plugin/client/_index');

    }

    public function renderTemplate($path, array $variables = array()) {

        $path = str_replace('users/', 'plugin/client/', $path);
        parent::renderTemplate($path, $variables);

    }   

}
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do this, but it seems to work,
so like this I can have my one view for Client edit, which is almost the same as users one.

My elementtype is look like this:

```
class Plugin_ClientElementType extends UserElementType
{

    public function getSources($context = null)
    {
        $sources = array(
            '*' => array(
                'label'    => Craft::t('Clients'),
                'criteria'  => array('groupId' => 1),
                'hasThumbs' => true
            )
        );
        return $sources;
    }

}
```

So all fine up to here. The problem is in that list:
[image]

where I list all my clients the url on the title in my case now `User1` is pointing to `admin/users/[ID]`
I would like to change it to `plugin/client/[ID]` if that possible I know that it has to be in the model like this:

```
class Pluign_ClientModel extends UserModel
{

    protected $elementType = 'Plugin_Client';


    public function getCpEditUrl()
    {
        return UrlHelper::getCpUrl('plugin/client/' . $this->id);
    }


}
```

But it seems that it's not coming from there. If someone can help me with this would be great. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution of this was under my nose,

I added this

```
public function populateElementModel($row){

  $model = Plugin_ClientModel::populateModel($row);
  return $model;

}
```

In `Plugin_ClientElementType` and then `getCpEditUrl()` it works.